# Using each promise value of Promise.map as input of the next loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise, bluebird, knex.js

I've done whole-day research on how I can get result of each promise in a `Promise.map` and use it as input in the next iteration during loop of that same `Promise.map`. I **strictly** need to do this approach because am using this logic in a **database operation** that **must be ATOMIC** and in case of any promise rejection all the previous transactions have to be rolled back.

**NOTE:** I have used `promise.each` and it works well only that it does not allow me to associate the individual promises and roll back **all** if one fails. So `Promise.map` seem to be the best solution when each promise is carefully resolved and value returned without causing `Error: Transaction query already complete` in the next loop. Here is the logic with knex:

```js
var obj={};

knex.transaction(function(trx) {
  return Promise.map(array, function(item) {
        return trx.insert(item).into('table')
        .then(returnedFields => {
        //do some validation/operation and return the result or the returnedFields themselves as input in the next loop.
        //[START EDIT: this responds to comment by @ Mikael Lepistö for clarity]
        //update obj here to be used in next loop
        //[END EDIT]
      });
    }, {concurrency: 1});
})
.then(function(inserts) {
  console.log(inserts.length + 'Items saved.');
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.error(error);
})
```

Comment: Thanks @RolandStarke, in my case (in the question) the returned promises are in the context of the transaction and any rejection will trigger automatic `rollback` wothout necessarily adding a `catch/then` as **stated in the documentation**

Comment: from https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/708 (and reading the first 3 answers). it seems like Promise.map does not grantee an execution order, so you can't rely on the _previous_ iteration.

Comment: Great, I noted this **order issue** has a work-around that works well for me though: 1. Using concurrency option of with `1 as value` 2. It seems any code at a point of `return.....` inside a `Promise.map` is executed sequentially e.g logging at the point where there is a comment yields sequential order but logging before `return Promise.map(array...` shows no sequence.

Comment: mmm, how about using `async function(trx) { for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){ const returnedFields = await trx.insert(item).into('table'); ... }`

Comment: Smart one, this is the same logic in `Promise.map` design. I've tried it and promise values still don't persist as input for next loop

Comment: I think i don't get it... "previous transactions have to be rolled back" do you start multiple transactions? In your code you only show one transaction. You can't rollback an already commited transaction.

Comment: The point there is that I need the promises to relate to each other in the `Promise.map` while individual results are passed to next loop, such that they all succeed or fail even if they are 10 in number

Comment: I don't quite see the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/n1fj6g43/1/

Comment: Thank you, testing immediately

Comment: I thoroughly tested your code and it works well except that it did'nt fit for my scenario. When I updated a `var json` (global variable)  with the output of every loop, I found out that it is still not updated during the next loop, I have decided to use `Promise.each` but doing some `rollback` and `commit` explicitly. Thanks alot.

Comment: This whole question is just confusing, based on false information (not showing that your code is actually are using transaction wrong way to get that error) and misleading. Just check any other question from stack overflow about how to use knex transactions or knex documentation about it and there is told that one should not mix returning promise from transaction callback / calling explicit commit / rollback methods.

Comment: @MikaelLepistö please look at the cod edit with `var obj` in response to your comment. To begin with,there is a first comment by @RolandStarke that is currently not visible and May be the reason you did'nt understand the flow about the question hence failing to relate well " **about the question** " and the " **question** ". To clarify problems: (1) `var obj` is updated when `Promise.map` is used but the update is not available during the next loop.(I had removed all `commits` and `rollback` calls in this case). (2) the mentioned error appear when `Promise.map` is used hence my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you everyone who posted great/greater insights. However it has turned out that `Promise.each` works well with `knex` and I was making a mistake of calling `commit` inside `then` of some individual `promises` during the loop hence causing `Error: Transaction query already complete` in next transaction attempt of the subsequent loop. **Reason:** There was no need calling `commit` withing the knex transaction context/block since it's automatically triggered in that context.

**To note in the answer below:**

Using `Knex` with `Promise.each` requires you to listen to possible rejection inside `then`block of each promise and with a `try/catch` and in some cases **explicitly reject** else the subsequent promises/values will continue looping and that cannot make **database atomic!!!**

```js
knex.transaction(function(trx) {
  return Promise.map(array, function(item) {
        return trx.insert(item).into('table')
        .then(returnedFields => {
        try{
        //do some validation/operation and return the result or the returnedFields themselves as input in the next loop.
        /* START Testing a case of rejection */
           if (array.indexOf(item) === 3) {
               //uncomment the code below to test
               //throw new Error('BreakException');
            }
        /* END */
        }catch(err){
        fail=true;
        }
      }).then(val => {
          if (fail) {
            trx.rollback()//you can ignore this as is automatically triggered here - tested
            return Promise.reject(new Error('Rejected'))
          }
          return val
        })
        .catch(err => {
          fail = true
          trx.rollback()//you can ignore this as is automatically triggered here - tested
          return Promise.reject(new Error('Rejected'))
        });
    });
})
.then(function(inserts) {
  console.log(inserts.length + 'Items saved.');
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.error(error);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
var promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
var promise2 = 42;
var promise3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values);
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Note the promises are dynamically created in the loop at the point of  `return trx.insert(item).into.....` and results are given for the next loop. They are not first initialized as in your case. However am trying out your approach if possible

Answer (score 0):

You can check out `async.js` library https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html

Here's what you can do

```
knex.transaction(function(trx) {
    return async.mapValuesSeries(array, (item) => {
        return trx.insert(item).into('table')
        .then(returnedFields => {
        //do some validation/operation and return the result or the returnedFields themselves as input in the next loop.
        });
    }, (error, inserts) => {
        if (err) { 
            console.error(error);
        }
        console.log(inserts.length + 'Items saved.');
    });
});
```